# Updating with has_one association and nested attributes is creating a new child object instead of updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, has-one

The code below shows the following setup with Rails 4, cocoon gem, and simple_form. Essentially, I have a bunch of clients in the DB, and I want to associate an existing one with an invoice via a select dropdown (selected by email).  When I do select an existing client by email, what happens is that a new client with the same email gets created.  This new client is not associated with any user.  Why is this happening?

EDIT: I think I may have set it up so that a client can only have one invoice per http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/ though that should still allow an update of the client child object to occur.

**Model setup**
    class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :client

  has_many :invoice_items, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :invoice

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**_form partial to be called with edit/update**

```
= simple_form_for [current_user, @invoice],  html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|

  - if @invoice.errors.any?

    #error_explanation

      %h2= "#{pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this invoice from being saved:"

      %ul

        - @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|

          %li= msg

  .form-group

    = f.label :paid, "Paid?"

    = f.input_field :paid

    %br/

  %h3 Client

  / = f.simple_fields_for :client, Client.new do |client|

  = f.simple_fields_for :client, Client.new do |client|

    = client.select :email, Client.all.map { |c| [c.email, c.email, { class: c.user.id }] }, include_blank: true

  = link_to "New Client", new_user_client_path(current_user)

  %h3 Invoice Items

  = f.simple_fields_for :invoice_items do |invoice_item|  

    = render 'invoice_item_fields', :f => invoice_item

  .links.form-group

    = link_to_add_association 'Add Invoice Item', f, :invoice_items, class: 'btn btn-primary'

  .actions

    = f.submit 'Submit'
```

**Invoices controller:**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :get_invoice_client, only: [:create, :update]

  before_filter :authenticate_user!



  # GET /invoices

  # GET /invoices.json

  def index

    @invoices = current_user.invoices

  end



  # GET /invoices/1

  # GET /invoices/1.json

  def show

  end



  # GET /invoices/new

  def new

    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build

    @invoice.client = @invoice.build_client

    @invoice_items = @invoice.invoice_items.build

  end



  # GET /invoices/1/edit

  def edit

  end



  # POST /invoices

  # POST /invoices.json

  def create

    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(invoice_params)

    @invoice.client = @invoice_client

    respond_to do |format|

      if @invoice.save

        format.html { redirect_to [current_user,@invoice], notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }

        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @invoice }

      else

        format.html { render action: 'new' }

        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end

    end

  end



  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json

  def update

    @invoice.client = @invoice_client

    binding.pry

    respond_to do |format|

      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)

        format.html { redirect_to [current_user, @invoice], notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }

        format.json { head :no_content }

      else

        format.html { render action: 'edit' }

        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end

    end

  end



  # DELETE /invoices/1

  # DELETE /invoices/1.json

  def destroy

    @invoice.destroy

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { redirect_to user_invoices_url(current_user) }

      format.json { head :no_content }

    end

  end



  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_invoice

      @invoice = current_user.invoices.find(params[:id])

      @invoice_items = @invoice.invoice_items

    end



    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def invoice_params

      params.require(:invoice).permit(:paid, :date_sent, :user_id, client_attributes: [:id, :email, :firstname, :lastname, :home_phone, :mobile_phone],

        invoice_items_attributes: [:id, :description, :line_total, :unit_cost, :quantity, :item, :invoice_id, :_destroy])

    end



    def get_invoice_client

      @invoice_client = Client.find_by_email(params[:invoice][:client_attributes][:email]) || nil

    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
= f.simple_fields_for :client, Client.new do |client|
```

to

```
= f.simple_fields_for :client, @invoice.client do |client|
```

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite work, but it did get my mind moving in a new direction.  I ended up changing the relationship from has_one to belongs_to on the invoice side, and belongs_to to has_many on the client side.  Then I no longer needed the nested attributes simple_fields_for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the relationship between Clients and Users, however if you have an existing table of clients . . .

```
Class Client
  has_one :user

Class User
  belongs_to :client, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoice_items, :through => :invoices

Class Invoice
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoice_items, :dependent => :destroy

Class Invoice_item
  belongs_to :Invoice
```

You could possibly consolidate the Client and User tables into one table as there is a one-to-one association between the two, but you can leave it as above.

If your primary form is for @client, then

```
= simple_form_for @client do |f|
  ... f.client fields ...
  = f.simple_fields_for @user do |u|
    ... u.user fields ...
  = f.simple_fields_for @invoices do |i|
    ... i.invoice fields ...
    = f.simple_fields_for @invoice_items do |t|
      ... t.invoice_item fields ...
```

Since you are using Haml, your indentation is critical.  If you extract your simple_field_for outputs into separate partials, it will be much easier to read and manage.  I left those out so you can see the relationships between your "nested" models.

Hope that helps.